# Why does this question appear twice in the hot list?

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-exchange-button, hot-questions

Allow me to refer you to my freehand circles:

[image: screenshot]

I *knew* Jeff really *does* like us folks over at Gaming!

Comment: You typed "Allow me to refer you to my freehand circles", but my brain saw "Give me infinite upvotes"

Comment: You mean the 40ish votes I got on my answer within a few hours weren't truly earned? :P

Comment: @Matthew It appears not. I think we'll let you keep them though. :P

Comment: Thank you for this question. Gimli's gender question was a nice read.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how to answer this question without a lot of hand waving and speculation based on what was happening at the time this occurred so I'm going to go with a default answer of c-c-c-caching.

We need to catch this one in the act so thanks for bring it to our attention.  I will be monitoring the hot list from Stack Exchange for dupes more diligently.

Closing this bug after waiting a full month for this issue to come up again.

Comment: Well then do you know why it has 2 different hotness values for the same question?

Answer (score 3):

Today we welcome another question so hot which needs to be listed twice!

[image]

Both links point to the same question [Need to reduce: $ \frac{(3-h) (3+h)}{h - 3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197683/need-to-reduce-frac3-h-3hh-3). Again, the two questions have different hotnesses.

[image]