# The new review stats cut the Reviewer badge in half

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Well because the freehand circles worked *so* well [last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111110/why-does-this-question-appear-twice-in-the-hot-list)...

[image]

Comment: on a somewhat related topic, did this encourage you to go about editing?

Comment: Oh yes!  I edited about 20 posts in a span of 20 minutes.  I had to stop so I didn't flood our front page.  :)  [I tend to go about editing anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111011/is-made-title-a-question-a-valid-reason-for-submitting-an-edit/111012#111012), but seeing stats is a wonderful encouragement and motivator!  (and something I've wanted for a long time)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the copy a bit and moved it around, should look fine on all sites now.

Comment: I have confirmed this.  And when did Reviewer become silver? (not complaining, I think it's a good change.)

Comment: @John yea see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing/111329#111329